# Python bot wont stop the while loop even after making the variable false

Tags: python, discord, bots

so I have been working on this bot for quite a while and have tried many ways to make the while loop stop, but non of them are making it stop. In the example below when I type on discord ?game stop X X I added a print statement to show me that swi in fact becomes False but then the bot keeps on posting. The first way I did it in was:

```
while swit != 'stop':
      await ctx.send(message)
      time.sleep(5)
```

But that too didn't work why is that? The code is the one below thank you in advance!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'we have logged in as {bot.user}')


@bot.command()
async def game(ctx, swit, ticker, message):
  swi = False
  if swit == 'stop':
    swi = False
  elif swit == 'start':
    swi = True
  while swi:
    if swi == False:
      break
    else:
      await ctx.send(message)
      time.sleep(5)


bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Once it's inside the loop, what can change its value?

Comment: Inside the `while swi` loop, there is no code to change the value of `swi`, so the loop runs forever.  How do you expect `swi` to change?

Comment: Once you're inside the while loop, it doesn't seem that `swi` can change to false.

Comment: Your `swi = False` and `swi = True` code runs only before the loop starts. So, even if `swit` changed to `'stop'` (which it can't since it's just a function parameter, not a global or a class variable), `swi` will never change.

Comment: Your `game` command is repeatedly called from outside as a bot command. Each time it gets called they run in their own "thread". Those values are set once in each "thread". (Those aren't real threads but in layman terms it is easier to understand. Your code runs asynchronous hence the `async` keyword.)